# Proving commutativity of type level addition of natural numbers

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, type-theory

I'm playing around with what tools haskell offers for dependently typed programming. I have promoted a GADT representing natural numbers to the kind level and made a type family for addition of natural numbers. I have also made your standard "baby's first dependently typed datatype" vector, parameterized over both its length and the type it contains. The code is as follows:

```
data Nat where
    Z :: Nat
    S :: Nat -> Nat

type family (a :: Nat) + (b :: Nat) :: Nat where
    Z + n = n
    S m + n = S (m + n)

data Vector (n :: Nat) a where
    Nil :: Vector Z a
    Cons :: a -> Vector n a -> Vector (S n) a
```

Furthermore I have made an `append` function that takes an m-vector, an n-vetor and return an (m+n)-vector. This works as well as one might hope. However, just for the heck of it, I tried to flip it around so it returns an (n+m)-vector. This produces a compiler error though, because GHC can't prove that my addition is commutative. I'm still relatively new to type families, so I'm not sure how to write this proof myself, or if that's even something you can do in haskell.

My initial thought was to somehow utilize a type equality constraint, but I'm not sure how to move forward.

So to be clear: I want to write this function

```
append :: Vector m a -> Vector n a -> Vector (n + m) a
append Nil xs         = xs
append (Cons x xs) ys = x `Cons` append xs ys
```

but it fails to compile with

```
    * Could not deduce: (n + 'Z) ~ n
      from the context: m ~ 'Z
        bound by a pattern with constructor: Nil :: forall a. Vector 'Z a,
                 in an equation for `append'
```

Comment: At least until somewhat recently, this kind of stuff didn't even work properly with GHC's built-in type-level numbers. Pragmatically speaking, this might still be one of the places where an `unsafeCoerce` is the most sensible fix.

Comment: @leftaroundabout The questioneer isn't using `TypeLits`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a full solution. Warning: includes some hasochism.

We start as in the original code.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DataKinds, TypeOperators, GADTs, PolyKinds #-}
{-# OPTIONS -Wall -O2 #-}
module CommutativeSum where

data Nat where
    Z :: Nat
    S :: Nat -> Nat

type family (a :: Nat) + (b :: Nat) :: Nat where
    'Z + n = n
    'S m + n = 'S (m + n)

data Vector (n :: Nat) a where
    Nil :: Vector 'Z a
    Cons :: a -> Vector n a -> Vector ('S n) a
```

The old append which type checks immediately.

```
append :: Vector m a -> Vector n a -> Vector (m + n) a
append Nil xs         = xs
append (Cons x xs) ys = x `Cons` append xs ys
```

For the other append, we need to prove that addition is commutative.
We start by defining equality at the type level, exploiting a GADT.

```
-- type equality, also works on Nat because of PolyKinds
data a :~: b where
   Refl :: a :~: a
```

We introduce a singleton type, so that we can pass `Nat`s and also pattern match on them.

```
-- Nat singleton, to reify type level parameters
data NatI (n :: Nat) where
  ZI :: NatI 'Z
  SI :: NatI n -> NatI ('S n)
```

We can associate to each vector its length as a singleton `NatI`.

```
-- length of a vector as a NatI
vecLengthI :: Vector n a -> NatI n
vecLengthI Nil = ZI
vecLengthI (Cons _ xs) = SI (vecLengthI xs)
```

Now the core part. We need to prove `n + m = m + n` by induction. This requires a few lemmas for some arithmetic laws.

```
-- inductive proof of: n + Z = n  
sumZeroRight :: NatI n -> (n + 'Z) :~: n
sumZeroRight ZI = Refl
sumZeroRight (SI n') = case sumZeroRight n' of
   Refl -> Refl

-- inductive proof of: n + S m = S (n + m)
sumSuccRight :: NatI n -> NatI m -> (n + 'S m) :~: 'S (n + m)
sumSuccRight ZI _m = Refl
sumSuccRight (SI n') m  = case sumSuccRight n' m of
   Refl -> Refl

-- inductive proof of commutativity: n + m = m + n
sumComm :: NatI n -> NatI m -> (n + m) :~: (m + n)
sumComm ZI m = case sumZeroRight m of Refl -> Refl
sumComm (SI n') m = case (sumComm n' m, sumSuccRight m n') of
   (Refl, Refl) -> Refl
```

Finally, we can exploit the proof above to convince GHC to type `append` as we wanted. Note that we can reuse the implementation with the old type, and then convince GHC that it can also use the new one.

```
-- append, with the wanted type
append2 :: Vector m a -> Vector n a -> Vector (n + m) a
append2 xs ys = case sumComm (vecLengthI xs) (vecLengthI ys) of
   Refl -> append xs ys
```

Final remarks. Compared to a fully dependently typed language (say, like Coq), we had to introduce singletons and spend some more effort to make them work (the "pain" part of Hasochism). In return, we can simply pattern match with `Refl` and let GHC figure out how to use the deduced equations, without messing with dependent matching (the "pleasure" part).

Overall, I think it's still a little easier to work with full dependent types. If/when GHC gets non-erased type quantifiers (`pi n. ...` beyond `forall n. ...`), probably Haskell will become more convenient.

Comment: Note that this is inefficient. `(:~:)` is a singleton type, but these proofs walk around the `Nat`s involved quite a bit before terminating. In real code, I’d rename `sumComm` to something else (but still *have* it so the compiler checks it), and write `sumComm :: forall n m. n + m :~: m + n; sumComm = unsafeCoerce Refl -- proof at ...`. Note the singleton arguments have been nixed. This also one of the nice-ish things about "Hasochism". You have very specific control over "erasure": everything is erased unless you reify it.

Comment: @HTNW Agreed. I wish GHC would perform this optimization itself (after having run a termination checker on the proofs).

Comment: this sure does seem to do the trick! I always kind of get a bit disappointed when I delve into dependent types and it turns out that to do anything really interesting it seems you have to resort to singletons which seem really hacky to me. I guess this is as good an excuse as any to start looking more at idris or agda maybe ^^

Comment: I will say though, it's really cool to see how closely this code resembles the theorems and proofs we went through in my class on first order logic last semester!

Comment: "To do anything really interesting it seems you have to resort to singletons which seem really hacky to me." The GHC team agrees with you, which is why they're working on adding full dependent types to the language... some time in the next 5 years or so

Comment: It's also worth noting that Haskell's types have a key difference to first order logic: that every statement is provable (using eg `let x = x in x`). Languages designed for theorem proving like Coq and Agda typically come equipped with a termination checker because "everything's true" is not a very desirable quality for a theorem prover

Comment: @HNTW Richard Eisenberg suggests using rewrite rules to implement your `unsafeCoerce` idea, so you don't need to duplicate and rename your proofs. https://typesandkinds.wordpress.com/2016/07/24/dependent-types-in-haskell-progress-report/

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson That would keep the singleton arguments around, meaning that e.g. `append` above would still need to pass arguments to `sumComm`. Whether the arguments are actually used depends on optimization level, so it is never safe to dummy them out. It just seems harder uglier than keeping everything at the type level. Another (unimplemented) idea that I have is an (overloaded) function `proof :: (Sing t1 -> ... -> l :~: r) -> l :~: r; proof _ = unsafeCoerce Refl` with usage like `sumComm :: forall n m. (n + m) :~: (m + n); sumComm = proof $ \(n :: SNat n) (m :: SNat m) -> _`